# KVO on NSObject not working for some reason

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, kvocontroller

I'm trying to implement `KVOController` in my app. I managed to get it working on custom `UISliders`, but I can't seem to get it working on a custom `NSObject`. This is the object:

**Restaurant.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Restaurant : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *name, *tagline;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) UIColor *uicolor;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)main;
- (void)setName:(NSString *)title;
- (void)changeColor:(UIColor)color;

@end
```

**Restaurant.m**

```
@implementation Restaurant

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)main {
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _name = main;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)title {
    _name = title;
}

- (void)changeColor:(UIColor)color {
    _uicolor = color;
}

@end
```

So, I introduced this listener into my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.restaurant = [[Restaurant alloc] initWithName:@"test"];
    [self.restaurant changeColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    FBKVOController *KVOController = [FBKVOController controllerWithObserver:self];
    self.KVOController = KVOController;

    [self.KVOController observe:self.restaurant keyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial|NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew block:^(id observer, id object, NSDictionary *change) {
        NSLog(@"Restaurant changed!");
    }];
}

- (void)someOtherMethod:(id)sender {
    [self.restaurant setName:@"Another test"];
    [self.restaurant changeColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

However, this isn't logging anything for this, nor when I change the `keyPath` to `@"uicolor"`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried using NSKeyValueChangeSetting as options?

Comment: Why is the property declared as `readonly` even though you also declare a public `setName:` method and call `setName:` from another class? Just make the property read-write, eliminate the extra `setName:` method in both the .h and .m.